# Parse Json Method POST windows phone app 8.1

Tags: json, post

I've down Method GET with HttpClient, but i dont know how to get data with param (id) or by method POST, anyone help me.
this is a code GET with HttpClient i use before, hope method POST same it.

```
public async void getreponse()
    {
        var postrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://210.86.239.156/PIXA/app_truyenhay/api/list_story");
        postrequest.Method = "GET";
        postrequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebResponse postresponse = (HttpWebResponse)await postrequest.GetResponseAsync();
        string response = String.Empty;
        if (postresponse != null)
        {
            var postResponseStream = postresponse.GetResponseStream();
            var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(postResponseStream);

            response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        ListStory liststory = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListStory>(response);
        /*foreach (var blog in liststory.items)
            blog.storyImage = "http://a.wattpad.com/cover/30539421-256-k910647.jpg";
        //LBTruyen.ItemsSource = liststory.items;                        */
    }
```

Comment: anyone help, how i can get list<object> with method POST

Comment: i only have link json, and params